# Xcode -- Alternate options for control+drag in story board to create a control segue for button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on ToDoList app in IPAD.

I am getting problem to control+drag the button(Done, Cancel) to point to the "Exit" button in the bottom due to scroll issues.when i zoom-in in the story board for "Add To-Do Item" screen.I cannot see the below green button to connect due to scroll issues.

Will there be any other way i can point the "Done" or "Cancel" button clicks to unwindList segue.

Please provide me with any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Open the storyboard, click on the little icon in the lower left corner called *"Show Document Outline"* [image: Show Document Outline]. You will see a list of elements with their names there. <kbd>Control</kbd>-Drag from the desired button name to **Exit**.

Answer (score 0):

Also, right-click any view (including a button) will pop a small window with a full list (outlets and all). That window can be moved and dragged, so you can place it next to the green 'Exit' and drag from there. This comes handy when you need to control-click-drag from/to views that are far or tricky (without dropping it in the wrong place).

I think 'Touch up inside' is the click gesture.